# mosaic raster image non georeferenced

Tags: qgis, raster, mosaic

I have several jpeg2000 tiles non georeferenced and covering a certain area. I know in qgis you can mosaic image using the merge tool but I have done it only using georeferenced images, which is quite straightforward.
I would like to know if there is a method with qgis to mosaic raster images non goreferenced. So basically just stitching tiles above, below, left and right.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround should work:

Create fake world files (.wld or .j2w). Use pixel size 1, -1 and put the origin of your master image into 1,1. Check the size of your images is pixels (width, height) with gdalinfo and calculate origins for the other tiles to match. Remember these:

- origin is at the center of the top-left pixel
- Y (northing) is decreasing from top to down
- putting origin into 0,0 would feel natural but in some cases it can make GDAL to do odd things and using 1,1 instead is more safe

[image]

The complete world file for tile1 would be

```
1.0
0
0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
```

Another option is to create a .vrt file from all the images with gdalbuildvrt utility and edit the resulting .vrt file http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html which is a XML text file.   element has roughly the same information as a world file.

Comment: thanks, how do you create in qgis such fake files? How do you change the origin of the upper left?

Comment: Use text editor, world file it is just 6 lines of plain text https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file. It you have image image.jp2 write a world file and save it as image.j2w. I added a world file for tile1 into my answer. As I wrote, this is a workaround but it will work.

Comment: I have done what you explained and I have created a tile containing the text you attached to the post. When loading in qgis it gives me an error.

Comment: What files do you have now? What is the error? Could you run gdalinfo for the image and paste the result? Or perhaps put the image and world file for downloading?

Comment: I run the gidal info on my image and i Have
Driver: JP2OpenJPEG/JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
Files: /Volumes/FREECOM HDD/image.jp2
       /Volumes/FREECOM HDD/image.jp2.aux.xml
Size is 424, 17390
Coordinate System is `'
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,17390.0)
Upper Right (  424.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  424.0,17390.0)
Center      (  212.0, 8695.0)
Band 1 Block=424x2048 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Overviews: 212x8695, 106x4347, 53x2173
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=12

Comment: I have tried also the method with gdalbuildvrt, the problem I have is that I can edit the file so shifting the second image, but when visualizing it I cannot display both the tiles. It seems the display excluding one of the other tiles handling them as separate bands

Comment: Your j2w file is not found. Is it in the same directory? Try by deleting the aux.xml file and also by renaming .j2w into .wld.

Comment: At the end I used gdalbuildvrt as you suggested. With this library I create the .vrt file, which I edit to shift the raster I want to mosaic. Doing this I create several "modified" .vrt, which produces shift raster in the mosaci